# Elementary OS Juno - Wifi not working

Tags: wifi, elementary-os

I recently installed Elementary OS Juno on my laptop which was on Windows 8.1. The installation is complete, I've done all of the updates (or if I don't it's not precised). I've done all of this with an Ethernet connexion (so with a wired connexion). But today I wanted to connect my laptop with the Wifi. I entered the access code (maaany times, so the problem isn't in the access code), and it was an abnormal long connexion, for at the end tell me it was impossible to connect. I've tested to connect with another source of connexion (a domino), and it works. Indeed, I don't know where the problem could be.

Here's the name of my wireless card (or what I think it is) : RTL8188EE Wireless Network Adapter from Realtek My laptop functions in 64 bits, and it's an HP (don't know what kind of)

`uname -a` reports `Linux Grimion 4.15.0-48-generic #51-Ubuntu SMP Wed Apr 3 08:28:49 UTC 2019 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux`

`lsusb` reports

```
 Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
    Bus 001 Device 004: ID 1a40:0101 Terminus Technology Inc. Hub
    Bus 001 Device 003: ID 04f2:b40e Chicony Electronics Co., Ltd HP Truevision HD camera
    Bus 001 Device 005: ID 046d:c077 Logitech, Inc. M105 Optical Mouse
    Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

`iwconfig` reports

```
 enp4s0    no wireless extensions.

    lo        no wireless extensions.

    wlp2s0    IEEE 802.11  ESSID:off/any  
              Mode:Managed  Access Point: Not-Associated   Tx-Power=off   
              Retry short limit:7   RTS thr=2347 B   Fragment thr:off
              Power Management:off
```